# Los clientes suscritos a Mercure hub desde Mozilla no reconectan automáticamente en caso de una caída y reinicio del hub, desde Chrome y Edge sí

Tags: symfony, symfony5, mercure-hub

me he dado cuenta que los clientes suscritos a un hub de Mercure no reconectan automáticamente (siempre y cuando su session en la aplicación web no haya expirado) si el servidor Mercure se detiene y entra en funcionamiento nuevamente. Enel caso de los clientes suscritos desde Edge o Chrome si reconectan automáticamente (siempre y cuando su session no haya expirado en la aplicación web).
De igual forma sucede cuando un usuario intenta generar un reporte digamos en Excel o PDF, al iniciarse la petición al servidor el cliente se desconecta del hub  de Mercure, y para los usuarios de Mozilla hay que recargar la página para que vuelva a suwcribirse, con otros navegadores la reconexión es autonatica.

Este comportamiento es atípico en mi caso o ya es conocido!?. Tengo Mozilla Firefox en su última versión sobre Windows 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Efectivamente, buscando un poco en SO otros usuarios explican que el comportamiento de los navegadores no es el mismo con el objeto EventSource, y para el caso de Mozilla Firefox incluso hasta la última versión, al ocurrir una desconexión provocada por el servidor, el navegador no es capaz de "reconectar". Mi caso específico provoca las desconexiones desde el Mozilla dos aspectos:

1. El usuario de la aplicación web genera un reporte en formato Excel, Word o PDF (de acuerdo a funcionalidades que tiene la aplicación), provocado por el stream de datos que genera el servidor.
2. Al estar configurada la URL de suscripción al Mercure hub mediante un **Proxy inverso** en Apache2, por regla por defecto de Apache2 se establece un `connectiontimeout` y un `timeout` de 60 segundos.

Ambos casos en otros navegadores, la reconexión es automática, más sin embargo en el Mozilla no.

La solución la encontré en [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24564030/is-an-eventsource-sse-supposed-to-try-to-reconnect-indefinitely), y de todas las propuestas me quedé con el uso del script [ReconnectingEventSource](https://github.com/fanout/reconnecting-eventsource), sustituyendo el objeto EventoSource por el mencionado una vez incluido el `script` anterior en plantilla:

```
const eventSource = new ReconnectingEventSource("{{ mercure(topic, { subscribe:topic})|escape('js')}}", {withCredentials: true, max_retry_time: 60000});
```

El resto del código se mantiene. Este objeto `ReconectingEventSource`, admite además una propiedad `max_retry_time` que la establecí a 60 segundos para mantener el tiempo de reconexión basado en el tiempo que establece timeout del proxy inverso de Apache2. De esta forma se resuelven los dos problemas que provocan desconexión al Mercure hub cada xx tiempo y que el Mozilla no es capaz de restablecer.